# Segmentation Fault when reading File

Tags: c, file-io, fgets

I am reading a file that stores information that I must later draw. When I read the file, I can collect the information I need (used `printf` just to verify that values were being stored in correct places) but I cant seem to leave the loop.

```
void getInfo(info *rooms, borderControl *doors, FILE *file)
{
char buffer[150];
char tempStorage[10];
char *temp;
char *locaOne, *locaTwo;

temp = tempStorage;
temp = malloc(sizeof(tempStorage));

while(fgets(buffer, 150, file) != NULL)
{
    printf("Inside fgets loop\n");
    temp = strtok_r(buffer, " ", &locaOne);
    rooms->size[0] = atoi(strtok(temp, "x"));
    rooms->size[1] = atoi(strtok(NULL, " "));
    temp = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &locaOne);

    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("Inside line loop\n");
        if (temp[0] == 'g') //gold
        {
            printf("Inside gold\n");
            temp++;
            rooms->gold[0] = atoi(strtok_r(temp, ",", &locaTwo));
            rooms->gold[1] = atoi(strtok_r(NULL, " ", &locaTwo));
            drawRooms(rooms, doors);
        }
        else if (temp[0] == 'h') //hero
        {
            temp++;
            rooms->heroPosi[0] = atoi(strtok_r(temp, ",", &locaTwo));
            rooms->heroPosi[1] = atoi(strtok_r(NULL, " ", &locaTwo));
            drawRooms(rooms,doors);
        }
        else if (temp[0] == 's') //staris
        {
            temp++;
            rooms->stairs[0] = atoi(strtok_r(temp, ",", &locaTwo));
            rooms->stairs[1] = atoi(strtok_r(NULL, " ", &locaTwo));
            drawRooms(rooms,doors);
        }
        else if (temp[0] == 'd') //doors
        {
            temp++;
            rooms->door[0] = atoi(strtok_r(temp, ",", &locaTwo));
            rooms->door[1] = atoi(strtok_r(NULL, " ", &locaTwo));
            drawRooms(rooms,doors);
        }
        else if (temp[0] == 'm') //magic
        {
            temp++;
            rooms->magic[0] = atoi(strtok_r(temp, ",", &locaTwo));
            rooms->magic[1] = atoi(strtok_r(NULL, " ", &locaTwo));
            drawRooms(rooms,doors);
        }
        else if (temp[0] == 'p') //potion
        {
            temp++;
            rooms->magic[0] = atoi(strtok_r(temp, ",", &locaTwo));
            rooms->magic[1] = atoi(strtok_r(NULL, " ", &locaTwo));
            drawRooms(rooms,doors);
        }
        else if (temp[0] == 'w') //weapon
        {
            temp++;
            rooms->weapon[0] = atoi(strtok_r(temp, ",", &locaTwo));
            rooms->weapon[1] = atoi(strtok_r(NULL, " ", &locaTwo));
            drawRooms(rooms,doors);
        }
        else if (temp == NULL)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            temp = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &locaOne);
            if(temp == NULL)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        temp = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &locaOne);
    }
    printf("here\n");
}
```

I call this function using:

```
FILE *file;
file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
if (file == NULL)
{
    printf("Error! Could not open file.\n");
    return 0;
}
else
{
    initscr();
    getInfo(rooms, doors, file);
}
```

There isn't any compiling error/warning but when I run the program, I get this:

```
Inside fgets loop
Inside line loop
Inside gold
Inside fgets loop
Inside fgets loop
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: I'm going to guess that rooms is NULL and ask for a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Show the calling code

Answer (score 2):

fgets() returns NULL only when characters couldn't be read.

What you need to do is check for feof(file). When you finish reading the file the EOF bit is set to 1 and feof() returns true;